# Best Way to Decouple Startup Configuration from Web Project in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, onion-architecture

Using MVC5, it has been very easy to create a bootstrapper project that had references to all layers, thus decoupling the UI layer from references to, lets say, infrastructure logic. The project would contain startup configuration logic, such as setting up the IoC container.

The way to do this was to define a startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        // startup configuration (IoC etc) goes here
    }
}
```

And then add a line in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Startup), "Start")]
```

Unfortunatelly, this approach no longer works with asp.net 5. I had a brief look at the documentation but all I found out was that the framework looks for a class named Startup within the Web project.

I also had a look within the `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting` [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/dfe427d3b32478db198f356ee22507b50461060d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting) which seems to be responsible for finding the Startup class. I can see some references to the configuration class, so there is a chance that the assembly can be loaded by using some kind of configuration setting, but I couldn't confirm this or determine which setting.

Also, if this is true, how could the Startup class be determined by using the `config.json` file, when the file itself is being loaded within the Startup class? Are there different options for configuring the startup assembly, like for example using an environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the assembly where the [`WebHostBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs) will look for the startup type.

Add an INI config file with the name `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini` to your `wwwroot` folder with the following contents:

```
[Hosting]
Application = App.Bootstrapper
```

Where `App.Bootstrapper` is the namespace of your application bootstrapper project.

The startup class will have to look the same though, e.g. with `ConfigureServices` and `Configure`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you're curious, you can see the logic for determining the startup type [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L114). If we specify the `Hosting:Application` key in the INI file, it will use that value in stead of `appEnvironment.ApplicationName`.

Comment: Thanks, I did spot the line getting the value from configuration but I didn't expect it to be an .ini file

Comment: @elolos the INI file configuration is passed from the [`Program`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Program.cs) class of the hosting layer.

Comment: Thanks Henk, this worked just fine, but with a slightly different syntax: `Hosting:Application = App.Bootstrapper`. Also note that for IIS to work, you have to copy the Bootstrapper library dll to the runtime folder of your web application.

Comment: @elolos did it work with syntax I provided? It should, since `Hosting` is the section.

Comment: Sorry, @Henk, both syntaxes work fine, it was probably a typo. Do you by any chance have a link to a documentation page about these settings?

Comment: For future reference, according to https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/269, the `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini` file may change to `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.json` in a future update of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to focus on this, in asp.net core rtm, you neither need any .ini nor .json, all you need to do is to call .UseStartup("NamespaceOfYourStartup") and make sure the assembly contained Startup class is in the same location where your asp.net core web project has published the files.