# Move Startup.cs to Class Library (Package) Project - ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working in a MVC 6 project, and moved my Startup.cs class from the Web Project to an Infraestructure Project, which is a Class Libary Package. 
I also added the packages required by the class (exactly the same as the Web Project) in Infraestructure/project.son:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8"
```

But when I run the app get the following exception:

```
A type named 'StartupDevelopment' or 'Startup' could not be found in assembly 'UI.Web'.
at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.FindStartupType
```

I didn't find any way for specifying the Startup.cs location to my another assembly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Way to Decouple Startup Configuration from Web Project in ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913467/best-way-to-decouple-startup-configuration-from-web-project-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicated, the beta of the framework of that answer was pre beta-8, all this stuff is for beta-8+, and there were many changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP .Net 5 uses a new [hosting framework](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/tree/dev/src) which will look for a class named **Startup** (Or Startup+environment as in StartupDevelopment, as explained [in the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html#startup-conventions)).

This hosting framework uses the class [`Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebHostBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs) in order to create the `IHostingEngine`, but more interestingly allows specifying the assembly where this class should be found.

- Looking [at the docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/startup.html?highlight=startup#the-startup-class), you will see this is possible by providing a configuration value with the key **Hosting:Application**.

The process for specifying this value depends on which version of the framework you are using. In case of beta7 and earlier, it also depends if you are using IIS or a dnx command to run the application.

---

**BETA8**

One of the [latest changes in beta8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx) is precisely related with the IIS Hosting model.

- The old Helios hosting component has been abandoned, and a new approach is used which allows running a dnx command when using IIS hosting. More details [in the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69)

This means in beta8 the process of setting the configuration value **Hosting:Application** will be the same regardless of whether you are using IIS or a dnx command:

- You can directly add an argument to the dnx command line definition in your **project.json**:

  ```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --Hosting:Application ClassLibrary1",
  },
  ```
- You can add a config argument to the dnx command line definition, which points to a json file where you can specify arguments used for starting the hosting:

  ```
  //project.json
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.json",
  },

  //hosting.json
  {  
    "Hosting:Application": "ClassLibrary1",
  }
  ```
- If you don't specify a config file, the framework will still look for a file named **Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.json** in your base folder. You can create that file and specify the startup class there.

  - In case you are curious, you can see this behavior defined in the [Program](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Program.cs) class of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting` assembly.

---

**BETA 7**

In beta7 and earlier, the process for specifying this configuration value was different depending if you were using IIS or a dnx command.

**Using a dnx command**

This is very similar to the way I have explained in the beta8 section except, except that hosting configuration file expected by the framework is an **.ini** file. (And if is not provided it won't look for by default for a Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.json file)

Basically if you open your project.json you will see a command named **web** defined like the following:

```
"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
},
```

You have 2 main options for adding the `Hosting:Application` configuration key:

- Add the parameter directly to the command definition

  ```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini --Hosting:Application ClassLibrary1"
  },
  ```
- Add it to the hosting.ini file:

  ```
  server=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener
  server.urls=http://localhost:5000
  Hosting:Application=ClassLibrary1
  ```

You can understand better the way this will work by looking at the [`WebHostBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs) class, which is used by the `Program.Main` function in [`Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/Program.cs)

Now you will need to tell VS to run the command instead of IIS. Which you can do by selecting the default run action:
[image: Choosing web or IISExpress when running project]

You can also configure the properties for each of those profiles in the project properties pages:
[image: Profile properties pages]

- If you want to use the web command instead of IISExpress you will probably want to select the **Launch URL** action, entering the root url for your site (Which should match the one you defined in your hosting.ini file).
- You also have the option of adding command line arguments, so you could define here the startup assembly entering `--Hosting:Application=ClassLibrary1`. (Although defining it here means it will only be applied when starting the app from visual studio)
- These settings are saved into a file `launchSettings.json` in the **Properties** folder of your project. (Will be created the first time you change the default settings) Of course you can also manually modify this file.

When you run/debug your project using the web command you will see a dnx window opened, the browser launched (If you selected Launch URL in the web profile) and the Startup class in the specified assembly is used. For example I moved Startup to a project named ClassLibrary1:
[image: Launching web command]

**Using IISExpress**

Since this is still using the old Helios hosting component, the process is different than when using a dnx command.

I have dig a bit in the code used to start the application using IISExpress and I have found that it is using `RuntimeHttpApplication.ApplicationStart` in the assembly `Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS`.

- This class is the one calling into the new `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting`, more concretely it is creating the `WebHostBuilder`, calling its `Build` method to get the `IHostingEngine` and finally calling `Start` in the engine.

Interestingly the configuration provided to the `WebHostBuilder` can include a file named **Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini** which must be found in the root path of the website. (Since it is looking for the file using `IHttpApplication.MapPath("/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini")`).

This means you can create a file named **Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini** (case insensitive) inside the **wwwroot** folder of your application, containing a single line like follows:

```
Hosting:Application=ClassLibrary1
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your great answer. I did it work but only once, no more. What I did was moving `Startup.cs` and `appsettings.json` to the class library project, install the packages used by Startup.cs, add the command:  `"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting server.name=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener server.urls=http://localhost:5001 --Hosting:Application ClassLibraryName"`, and added an entry to ClassLibrary/project.json specifying a shared file (like [here]https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#shared-files). I don't know if all this is right, but I'll keep trying.

Comment: I have just tried beta8 and it works fine, I have updated the answer. For moving the class I created a new class library project, moved the startup class there, copied the dependencies and frameworks sections of the original MVC projec.json. Then I added a reference from the MVC project to the class library (Since you are still using the MVC project as the starting one where dnx commands are defined)

Comment: Well, it seems it worked, **thank you** for your effort. Just a couple of things I'd like to know: **1-** the `framework/dnxcore50` section of project.json in ClassLibrary1 doesn't need all the default packages that come by default? You just deleted it?  **2-** I realized that all the packages both, in Web and in ClassLibrary1 projects, are _now_ duplicated, for example, MVC, ConsoleLogging, and so on. I don't think it's a good thing, so I deleted all the `dependencies` section in project.json in Web, except the reference to ClassLibrary1. Is this ok? It seems work ok, but I am not sure....

Comment: In regards to the first question, seems like just adding, at least, one package, **any of them** that supports both 4.5.1 and core, to the general dependencies section (not dnx451/dependencies or dnxcore50/dependencies), the minimum required packages are included automatically (Microsoft.CSharp, System.Collections, etc.)  Deleting absolutely all dependencies makes possible compilation only available for 4.5.1 (I suposse because of the libraries included in the SO .NET framework)

Comment: Regarding 1, I copied the whole dependencies and framework sections. Regarding 2, reading [the docs](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#adding-dependencies) what I understand is that if you depend on ClassLibrary1, then you also depend on everything ClassLibrary1 depends on. (Which explains your own answer to question 1)

Comment: Tried your suggestion for beta8, however it didn't work. The error I got was "System.IO.FileNotFoundException 
Could not load file or assembly 'Bootstrapper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

In beta7, IISExpress was able to find the assembly using the "projects" node in global.json where I specified "source" and in Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini under wwwroot folder I just specified Hosting:Application=Bootstrapper. Any thoughts?

Also, is there a way to make this work without adding any references between the Bootstraper and MVC projects?

Comment: Have you added a reference in the MVC project to your bootstrap prohect? I had to do that for beta8

Comment: Wouldn't adding this reference defeat the purpose of having the Bootstrapper project in the first place? We are following the DDD pattern and keeping the Infrastructure assembly separate from the MVC project, with the Bootstrapper project containing the DI code. Referencing the Bootstrapper project in the MVC project would make the Infrastructure code available in there.

Since it was possible to omit this reference in beta7, can you think of a way to do this in beta8?

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how can you include the bootstrap project without referencing it from the one you are starting. It sounds like a nice ASP 5/dnx  question to me!

Comment: In beta7 it was possible, you just had to specify the projects within the global.json file in solution items. Thanks for the suggestion, I will probably post a question for this.

Comment: I just added an issue to github with the same question: [https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1010](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1010)