# Asp.Net 5 MVC 6 Startup.cs Assembly Decoupling in Beta8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an eCommerce site using Asp.Net 5 and MVC6 following Onion Architecture (OA) so that we have loose coupling between the layers. I also want to decouple Startup code in its own assembly rather than having it in the MVC project.

In beta7 It was very easy to move the Startup.cs to a class library (Bootstrapper) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913467/best-way-to-decouple-startup-configuration-from-web-project-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc). One interesting fact using the mentioned approach is that I didn't have to reference the Bootstrapper assembly from the MVC project. At runtime, hosting under IISExpress, through assembly scanning it was able to find the Bootstrapper assembly mentioned in the Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini file. This was possible by specifying the location in the global.json

```
{
  "projects": [ "Source/Projects","Source/Bootstrapper" ],
  "sdk": {
        "architecture": "x64",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "version": "1.0.0-beta7"
    }
}
```

The Bootstrapper project will have reference to all other projects like Infrastructure, Services etc in order to hook up Dependency Injection.

The reason for not referencing the Bootstrapper project in MVC project, following Onion Architecture rules, is to avoid having access to Infrastructure code directly from MVC project. So this was all working fine until I upgraded to Beta8 this morning.

As the hosting model is changed from IIS to Kestrel, I had to refactor the global.json and project.json files as below

**global.json**

```
{
  "projects": [ "Source/Projects","Source/Bootstrapper" ],
  "sdk": {
        "architecture": "x64",
        "runtime": "clr",
        "version": "1.0.0-beta8"
    }
}
```

**project.json**

```
{ 
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "....",
    "....",
},

 "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"   
    } 
}
```

After making the above changes, I started getting the following error regardless whether I run it using dnx command or directly via Visual Studio

> Internal Server Error System.InvalidOperationException A
>   type named 'StartupDevelopment' or 'Startup' could not be found in
>   assembly 'EcommerceMvcApp'. at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.FindStartupType(String
>   startupAssemblyName, IList diagnosticMessages)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureStartup()  at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()

Turned out that I have to specify the config file or inline arguments to the web command as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183357/move-startup-cs-to-class-library-package-project-asp-net-5/33190940#33190940). After following the suggestion, I tried running the application and this time I started getting the error below

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly
>   'Bootstrapper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
>   file specified. at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.FindStartupType(String
>   startupAssemblyName, IList diagnosticMessages)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureStartup()  at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183357/move-startup-cs-to-class-library-package-project-asp-net-5/33190940#33190940) requires that I add a reference to the Bootstrapper project in the MVC project and it works. However, it defeats the purpose of having a separate Bootstrapper assembly in the first place.

The question is, why it is unable to find the Bootstrapper assembly like it used to do in Beta7, using the sources specified under "projects" in global.json or is the new hosting model ignoring the global.json? Is there a way to specify the location of the Startup assembly?

**Update 1**

Just want to highlight that in Beta7 it also works using "dnx command" for both Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener and Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.

```
"commands": {
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5004 --config wwwroot/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini",
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5004 --config wwwroot/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.ini"
    }
```

However, the dnx command (using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.json file) fails for both servers in Beta8. If someone is wondering that it's something to do with IIS Helios component in Beta7, it's not the case. I am baffled as why the assembly lookup stopped working in Beta8

**Update 2**

Here is the stack trace that I get when I try to run in Beta8 using IISExpress. Looks like it's trying to find the assembly in the dnx bin folder.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Bootstrapper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the
>   file specified. File name: 'Bootstrapper'    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.FindStartupType(String
>   startupAssemblyName, IList`1 diagnosticMessages)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureStartup()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.BuildApplication()
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Bootstrapper  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: Bootstrapper | Domain ID: 1 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/sshassan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8/bin/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/sshassan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8/bin/Bootstrapper.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/sshassan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8/bin/Bootstrapper/Bootstrapper.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/sshassan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8/bin/Bootstrapper.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/sshassan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8/bin/Bootstrapper/Bootstrapper.EXE.

Perhaps, if I run dnu publish and host it under IIS it will work, but that means that I would have to publish it every time I make the change

Comment: You should really take this to the [aspnet/Home repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/) ans ask for assistance there.

Comment: Could you achieve it? Now that RC1 was released, maybe it's easier.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. I think with the new entry point in the Startup file i.e. Main method it might be possible. I will give it a go

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in a similar problem. It looks like we do not want to make references from UI layer to Infraestructure layer (we are very stricts), not even for making the dependency resolution.

Maybe it is possible by using **late binding** (I just heard talked about it), but I think that you should read [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/). It basically says that a Composition Root isn't reusable, and there should be one per application (i.e., one for UI.Web, another for UI.Console, and so on).

That responds also my question about what having the DI resolution in UI.Web, but need another UI, let's say Console (answer: it's preferable to make anoter DI resolution in Console, and **it'll have it's own resolution dependences related to how a Console Application actually works**).

I hope having give you a good point to clarify this issue.

Comment: Thanks Franco. +1 for referring to the excellent article. I read an [article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) a while ago, by the same guy, on the same topic and since then I follow the rule i.e. making the CR as close as possible to the entry point.  I totally agree with Mak and three applications in my solution have their own CRs. However, my problem is not reusing the CR, but decoupling it from the application's entry point. This will make the UI layer independent of the DI container and transient dependencies between UI, Infrastructure and Services layer.

Comment: Pre Asp.Net 5, decoupling of a CR was easily achievable by using the assembly level [PreApplicationStartMethod](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/) attribute.  It was also working in Beta7 but I asked the question at GitHub as well and according to David Fowler it worked because of the bug in beta7.  See the question [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/433#issuecomment-150122556). Perhaps, as David suggested I would need to write a custom assembly loader. However, this feature could have been provided by passing arguments to dnx

Comment: Well, I understand your point. However, now I do not find value in trying decouple such things. I can simply say that my dependency resolution **knows** about all my layers (UI, Services and Infraestructure). That means my application is glued in the UI, the actual application, and its persistence mechanism could be different from a Console App. If it would be the same, I would write the DI again, but differently. I do not know if I can transmit you the point

Comment: I got your point, Franco. In my solution, DI layer knows about all other layers. IMHO there is a value in decoupling the CR from the UI layer. First, writing DI code in Globla.asax/Startup.cs convolutes it. Second, If the DI is glued into the UI layer, it knows about all other layers. This violates the DDD/Onion Architecture principle i.e. dependencies should be towards the centre and there should be no transitive dependencies between the layers at the same level i.e. UI, Infrastructure and Services.

Comment: Moreover, it also makes it difficult to deploy the DI related code in isolation without creating a separate branch. This is a scenario where UI layer has some changes that are not supposed to go on Production.  Again, I am not disagreeing with the fact that CR and DI are application specific but decoupling them makes the life much easier. It was supported previously and it is also supported today by providing  "hosting:application" argument to a command in project.json. However, I have to reference that assembly in the UI layer rather than dynamically loading it from the bin path as it used to

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you, but I think I gave up with this and decided add the references. I just see this issue on github [https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2867](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2867). See if it's useful for your purpose, maybe it's possible add a Startup class to a separated class library, and making there the composition.

Answer (score 0):

The hosting config file format changed from INI to Json. Try this:

```
{  
  "Hosting:Application": "Bootstrapper",
}
```

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/269).

Comment: Yes, I am already using hosting.json file. The problem is not the hosting file. The second error message in my question indicates that it's looking for a Bootstrapper assembly. However, it cannot find it